# Calculate cosine similarity from tf-idf

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, scikit-learn, text-classification, cosine-similarity

In a data frame `df` I have a following column `tf-idf`:

```
       tf-idf
0      {u'selection': 3.83579393163, u'carltons': 7.0...
1      {u'precise': 6.43261849762, u'thomas': 3.31980...
2      {u'just': 2.70047792082, u'issued': 4.42829758...
3      {u'englishreading': 9.88788310056, u'all': 1.6...
4      {u'they': 1.89922701484, u'gangstergenka': 10....
5      {u'since': 1.45530416153, u'less': 3.956522477...
6      {u'exclusive': 10.4488880129, u'producer': 2.6...
7      {u'taxi': 6.04485296662, u'all': 1.64302370465...
8      {u'houston': 3.93463976627, u'frankie': 6.0306...
9      {u'phenomenon': 5.74474837417, u'deborash': 10...
10     {u'zwigoff': 19.7757662011, u'september': 1.90...
11     {u'gospels': 7.9419729515, u'theft': 6.0028887... `
```

I am struggling to find `cosine similarity` between two samples - for example between `df['tf-idf'][0]` and `df['tf-idf'][1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use scikit-learn:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

a = DictVectorizer().fit_transform(df['tf-idf'])
cosine_similarity(a[0], a[1])
```

Comment: @chintans, great to hear! did it work without `.tolist()` ?

Comment: Just one more question. If there are 50000 sample, i.e. `df.shape[0] = 50000` is there a quicker way to obtain the similarity matrix (without running two for loops)?

Comment: try `cosine_similarity(a)`. It should return all pairwise similarities.

Comment: OK...let me try that... Thanks!

Comment: Yep thats a CPU and memory intensive operation. Try checking you are not ram swapping cause that makes everything slower.

Comment: Sure thing, I will have a look at it.